# Not able to select element in appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

There is app called Raaga. I'm trying to automate this application using Appium and selenium but when I launched the app after splash screen a popup comes asking "Choose account for Raaga" as soon as the popup gone then there is screen which ask for login and sign up stuff but when I try to find the element it always throw no element found. Please let me know if m wrong I'm new to this. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
TouchAction act = new TouchAction(driver);
act.tap(241,320).perform();  

synchronized (driver)
{
driver.wait(4000);
}

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"SIGN IN\")").click();
```

[Here is first screen where the pop up comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syY8F.png)

[This is second screen which comes after the popup and I want to click on the "SIGN IN" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCkSo.png)

[Screenshot of UiAutomator with SIGN IN button selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zpCk.png)

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot with UIAutomatorViewer by selecting SIGN IN button?

Comment: Or you can try by using this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='SIGN IN']")).click();`

Comment: @AlImran I added the screenshot with UiAutomator with SIGN IN button selected.

Comment: Have you tried with element-id?

Comment: Still same no element found exception.

Comment: Yes, I tried with everything.

Comment: Add thread sleep before clicking on the element, and try below solutions

Comment: Still same. I don't know what the hell is happening. May be should try the same.

Comment: Remove splash screen from the app, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

So, you should try by using `resource-id` or `xpath`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("user_signin_btn")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.raaga.android:id/user_signin_btn")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='SIGN IN']")).click();
```

Comment: Please try above solution.

Comment: Still same. No luck.